# Teamcity LDAP encryption

Tags: ldap, teamcity, password-protected

I wondering if it is possible to use [teamcity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) with LDAP encrypted master password?

The idea is to be able to use LDAP with Teamcity without ability to get access to LDAP master passwords (create/edit users knowing this password).

Answer (score 1):

LDAP authentication usually works like this: The LDAP client (which would be the TeamCity server in this case) asks the LDAP server if a certain username/password combination is valid. The LDAP server checks this and answers with yes or no. At no point does it transmit the password back to the client. From my short skimming the docs, I understand TeamCity uses this method as well, so the answer would be yes.

You should just make sure that you use LDAP over SSL so that the password the TeamView server transmits to the LDAP server is encrypted as well and can't be sniffed.